# How to exit `if` statement inside `for` loop

Tags: ruby, loops, if-statement, break

I'm looping over an array, and have an `if` statement inside.

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9].each do |i|
  if i == 4
    p i
    break
  end
  if i > 6
    p i
  end
end
```

I want to print `i` if `i == 4`, and break, but still move on to the second `if` statement. How can I exit the `if` statement but not the `for` loop, still running the remaining code after the `if` block?

In my real scenario, I have a matrix:

```
  1     2     3     4     5 
  _     ♙     _     9     _ 
 11    12    13    14    15 
 16     _    18    19    20 
 21    22    23    24     _
```

Say my current pos is `[1][1]`. When I check my next element 
`(row + i, col)`, I want to increment a value. But when I encounter '_' say `[3][1]`, I should terminate from `if` statement.

Comment: Do you want this to print out `4 7 8 9`?

Comment: For this example yes (this is easy) because all we can do is remove the `break`. But I want to get `4 7 8 9` using break or next or whatever. The idea is breaking from one if statement and still continue with the rest if statements @Schwern

Comment: I did not get what do you mean by break if statement. 'break' is used to break loop and here you are doing it inside if statement which execute for once. You do not need break statement because it will break entire loop. 'continue' is another keyword which will ignore next code and continue with next each argument

Answer (score 2):

> *I know that a simple fix is just to remove the break. But the main question is, how can I break from one if statement, and still go to the second if statement.*

Remove the `break`.

There's no need to `break` out of `if` statements. They aren't loops. If the condition is true they run their block of code once and then continue onward.

```
this = 42

if this < 40
  p "less than 42"
end

if this > 40
  p "greater than 40"
end

p "after the ifs"
```

This will print.

```
"greater than 40"
"after the ifs"
```

Comment: What I'm trying to do, is stop if statement after the first occurrence, so how can i exit if statement when `i == 4`?

Comment: @Jamy I'm sorry, I don't understand what "exit if statement" or "terminate from if statement" means. I don't understand what you want to do from your matrix example, either.

Answer (score 1):

By "break from if", do you perhaps mean "interrupt execution of if's body"?

```
if condition
  puts 'doing something'
  # "break" here
  puts 'doing something else'
end
```

If so, it can be done like this:

```
catch(:break_from_if) do
  if condition
    puts 'doing something'
    throw :break_from_if
    puts 'doing something else'
  end
end
```

Note the verb: **can** be done, but **shouldn't ever** be done (in code that is of any importance)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am missing something. Unfortunately I am not entirely sure that I understand your question and the terminology that you use. The following makes sure that 'i > 6' does not have side-effects, in the same if block we perform the following check with elsif. Here you want the effect that you move onto the next item in the list, if I understand correctly. You can do that with 'next'.

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9].each do |i|
  if i > 6
    p i
  elsif i == 4
    p i
    next
  end
end
```